# Detecting text matching specific regex in dplyr

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, text

I hope all is well.
I need to find which row has:

1. only the term `pro` with an `space before` and no `characters after`, or
2. the term `certificat` with an `space before`, and characters can be after such as `certificate` or `certification`, or
3. any `digit` (could be `one digit or more`)

A piece of data is

```
df_new <- data.frame(
  given_info=c('SA12 is given','he is Pro writer',
               'she programmed','why not having an ra31',
               'his bag missing', 'pa12 and certificate are given',
               'schedule is ready','certification was awarded',
               'meeting is canceled'))

df_new %>% select(given_info)
```

```
                      given_info
1                  SA12 is given
2               he is Pro writer
3                 she programmed
4         why not having an 1672
5                his bag missing
6 gift and certificate are given
7              schedule is ready
8      certification was awarded
9            meeting is canceled
```

Hence, the outcome of interest would be like:

```
                      given_info      string_detected
1                  SA12 is given              1
2               he is Pro writer              1
3                 she programmed              0
4         why not having an 1672              1
5                his bag missing              0
6 gift and certificate are given              1  
7              schedule is ready              0
8      certification was awarded              1
9            meeting is canceled              0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew. I really admire the consistency with which you remove all this regex tags, but I don't understand why you're doing it. I'm convinced that this is a regex tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

- `(^|\\s)[Pp]ro(\\s|$)` ... matches the word "Pro" or "pro" surrounded by whitespace or appears at the beginning or end of the string
- `(^|\\s)[Cc]ertificat(e|ion)?(\\s|$)`... matches either "[Cc]ertificate", "[Cc]ertification", or "[Cc]ertificat" surrounded by whitespace or appears at the beginning or end of the string.
- `\\d+`... matches any sequence of one or more digits.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df_new %>%
  mutate(string_detected = as.integer(str_detect(given_info, "(^|\\s)[Pp]ro(\\s|$)") |
                                        str_detect(given_info, "(^|\\s)[Cc]ertificat(e|ion)?(\\s|$)") |
                                        str_detect(given_info, "\\d+")))
```

```
                      given_info string_detected
1                  SA12 is given               1
2               he is Pro writer               1
3                 she programmed               0
4         why not having an ra31               1
5                his bag missing               0
6 pa12 and certificate are given               1
7              schedule is ready               0
8      certification was awarded               1
9            meeting is canceled               0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing such a complete answer.  i noticed that other than ```pro``` there are other terms such as```med```, ```ted```, ```role```, and etc that I need to address. Is there a way to put all these in an array and use it in the code instead of reapeating every single term in the code? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With `base::grepl()`, using `\b` to identify word boundaries and `ignore.case = TRUE`:

```r
df_new$string_detected <- as.integer(grepl(
  "\\bpro\\b|\\bcertificat|\\d", 
  df_new$given_info, 
  ignore.case = TRUE
))

df_new
```

```
                      given_info string_detected
1                  SA12 is given               1
2               he is Pro writer               1
3                 she programmed               0
4         why not having an ra31               1
5                his bag missing               0
6 pa12 and certificate are given               1
7              schedule is ready               0
8      certification was awarded               1
9            meeting is canceled               0
```